# NSLayoutConstraint conflict in UITableViewCell with row hight set using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have reduced my code down to a minimum of what is required to generate the error. I have a tableviewcell that is completely programatic with only an image view in the content view. The image view should take up the entire content view.

I  constrain the image view:

1. to the top of the content view
2. to the bottom of the content view
3. leading edge of the content view
4. trailing edge of the content view

Lastly I constrain the image views hight and width
to each other based on the existing ratio of the image view it self.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier: (NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_foo"]];
        self.splashImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.splashImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.splashImageView];
        NSDictionary * viewDictionary = @{@"splashImage":self.splashImageView };
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.splashImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.splashImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:(self.splashImageView.image.size.height/self.splashImageView.image.size.width) constant:1];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[constraint]];

        NSArray * splashConstraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[splashImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];
        NSArray * splashConstraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[splashImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:splashConstraint_H];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:splashConstraint_V];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Sense the width of a table cell is known this should be enough information to determine height.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b6730c0 UIImageView:0x80eda630.height == 1.02133*UIImageView:0x80eda630.width + 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b673020 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x80eda630]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x80e1a590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x80ee3ca0 H:[UIImageView:0x80eda630]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x80e1a590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x80ee3cd0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x80eda630]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x80e1a590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x80ee3d00 V:[UIImageView:0x80eda630]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x80e1a590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x80ed8760 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x80e1a590(328)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x80ed8730 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x80e1a590(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b6730c0 UIImageView:0x80eda630.height == 1.02133*UIImageView:0x80eda630.width + 1>
```

Looking at the constraints that the imageview height, width relationship constraint is failing.

But why?
328(height) == 1.02133*320(width)+1
1.02133*320(width)+1 => 327.8256
which should round to the nearest pixel for non-retina and to the nearest .5 pixel for retina displays.

Sense the above works for the iPhone 6, but fails for both iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s it seems unrelated to retina vs non-retina. And regardless 327.8256 should round to 328.

Let me be clear that there are ways around this problem (adding width & height constraints that are explicit). I am not looking for a work around but instead trying to understand what is causing this behavior.

Comment: you can't pin the image view to all of the edges and ask it to keep the aspect ratio at the same time.. thats the conflict.  So just set a maximum height based not the height of your cell and pin top space, leading space, and trailing space

Comment: Pinning the image to all edges is a requirement for auto sized tableview cells.

The height of the cell should be defined by the height of the image view, the height of the image view is defined by a ratio to width, the width is defined by the width of the tableview cell which is defined by the parent view. How is this a conflict?

Comment: Well your error message clearly tells you why this is a conflict dealing with the height... how about you post a picture of your image view with the constraints and the result when you run on the simulator... you can't pin the image view to all of the edges and ask it to keep the aspect ratio at the same time.. thats the conflict

Comment: I don't believe the error message is clear. I even show how the relationship between the height and width are in fact equal after rounding.

Secondly the appearance of the image is not the issue in question. But rather, why is this a conflict. A fixed width frame, with a adjustable height can match any ratio. So why would there exist a hight conflict?

Comment: i have faced this error once, it looked harmless, just a float precision error, but to solve the problem, choose a constrain of one side of imageview and convert it to greater than 0, and add extra constraint to same place with same items and attributes and set up the relation less than 1. It will fix the problem. This will create a gap for imageview to lay itself with 1 pixel of error margin without constraint errors.